# How can I start using the JavaScript import/export features right now in my browser?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

How can I start using modules with the import statement in my browser?
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: short answer: SystemJS

Comment: The common approach right now is Babel and Webpack, have you explored those?